# why holomorphic function $f$ can't extends continuously to its boundary such that $f(z)=1/z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there is no holomorphic function $f$ in the unit disc $\Bbb{D}$ that extends continuously to $\partial \Bbb{D}$ such that $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$ for $z \in \partial \Bbb{D}$.

where $\Bbb{D}=\{z\in \Bbb{C} : |z|<1\}$

Comment: so $f$ is holomorphic for $|z|<1$ only and not for $|z|\leq 1$ ?

Comment: @Rush: I guess, you mean $f$ is holomorphic on the *open* unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ and extends continuously to $S^1=\partial \overline{\mathbb{D}}.$

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani,yes, you are right.

Comment: For the record I think this is in Stein and Shakarchi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume such an extension exists, then

**Solution 1**:Define $g(z)=zf(z),$ by the mean value property of holomorphic functions

$$0=g(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} g(e^{it}) dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} 1 \,dt = 1$$

which is a contradiction.

**Solution 2**: We have $|f(z)|=1$ on $S^1.$ Since $f$ is continuous on the boundary $\partial \overline{D}=S^1$ then, by maximum modulus principle, it attains its maximum on the boundary $S^1.$ ($f$ is not constant.) Consequently, $f(D) \subseteq D.$ WLOG assume that $f(0)=0$, therefore, by Schwarz lemma $f(z)=az$ where $|a|=1.$ Moreover, we should have $az=1/z$ on $S^1$, that is, $a.1=1/1 \rightarrow a=1$ and $ai=1/i=-i \rightarrow a=-1.$ Hence, a contradiction.

Comment: CIT requires $z f(z)$ to be holomorphic on a neighborhood of the closed disc.  That requires some more explanation.

Comment: The contradiction should be $0=\int_{S^1}f(z)dz=\int_{S^1}\frac{1}{z}dz=2\pi i$.

Comment: @WimC: CIT(a stronger version) only assumes the function is holomorphic in the interior and continuous on the closure.

Comment: @WimC: See the middle of the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem

Comment: @Landscape: Yes, I wanted to first write it, but this way has some hidden aspect :)

Comment: For solution 2 you could use $z f(z) - 1$ instead, which vanishes on the unit circle.

Comment: The present version of solution 1 looks good to me, but "by Cauchy" seems not in an explicit way. Maybe "by mean value theorem" sounds better. For solution 2, I agree with @WimC, but I don't understand why you can assume $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Landscape: I've edited the first one to "mean value property". For the second one, doesn't $h(z)=f(z)-f(0)$ works equally the same?

Comment: Then the boundary condition $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ will change.

Comment: @Landscape: For $h$ we'd have $h(z)=az$ so $f(z)=az+f(0)=\frac{1}{z}$ again different values for $a,$ right?

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani: Yes, and you can also get a contradiction from that.

Comment: Schwarz's lemma does not imply $f(z)=az$: for example $f(z)=z^n$ still satisfies your hypotesis, i.e. $|f(z)|=1$ on $S^1$, $f(\mathbb{D})\subseteq\mathbb{D}$ and $f(0)=0$.